# Text field is permanently in the second view controller upon segue

Tags: swift, segue, textfield

I have been working on an app that allows multiple text fields from the first view controller pass over to the second view controller upon pressing a button. However, the text fields are permanently in the second view controller when I only want them to be if the button is pressed. Here is the code for the first view controller! Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!

    @IBAction func buttonTwo(_ sender: Any) {
        if textField1.text != "" {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)        
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonOne(_ sender: Any) {
        if textField.text != "" {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var secondController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        secondController.myString1 = textField1.text!
        secondController.myString = textField.text!
    }
}
```

Here is the code in the second view controller:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

    var myString = String()
    var myString1 = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label.text = myString
        label1.text = myString1
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.    
    }
}
```

[Image of storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbi97.png)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, prepare for segue will be called every time you perform some segue action.

You should manage to have a bool variable that helps you track, if any button is clicked or not, if the segue is performed from the click of the button, then only you will have to set the text while preparing for segue.

here is your updated viewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!

var isButtonClicked: Bool = false

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    /*reset isButtonClicked to false, when you back from second viewController */
    isButtonClicked = false
}

@IBAction func buttonTwo(_ sender: Any) {
    if textField1.text != "" {
        isButtonClicked = true
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonOne(_ sender: Any) {
    if textField.text != "" {
        isButtonClicked = true
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if isButtonClicked {
        var secondController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        secondController.myString1 = textField1.text!
        secondController.myString = textField.text!
    }
}
}
```

Try and share your results.

Comment: Hi Bhavin, It still doesn't seem to work. Is it a problem that I only have one button to click? Im making an app where only one button is needed but im not sure if this affects the variable. Thanks for your help

Comment: Your problem is not clear. You are mentioning, you have one button and you wrote code for two buttons actions. Please edit you question with the screenshot of your storyboard showing the UI, to help you better on this problem.

Comment: Hi Bhavin, apologies.. that comment from me was confusing. I meant I have one button for one segue and another button for another segue. Clicking on buttonOne will input the textField into the label. Clicking on buttonTwo will input textField1 into label1. But at the moment if i click on either button it fills the textfields into the labels simultaneously. I hope this clears things up. I have added the storyboard into the question.